# Differentiaing between Group vs Individual chat in #microsoft-teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Moving off Skype onto teams seems okay but i can not differentiate between GroupChat v Individual Chat sounds. Being able to tailor would be nice. #microsoft-teams

Comment: Your question is not very clear - please elaborate. Are you talking about in the UI? In the API? Something else?

Comment: @R J Jamison : Could you please elaborate your use case as to what you are trying to achieve, this will help us to solve the issue quickly. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The audio notices in MSTEams are the same for a group chat or an individual chat.
It would be helpful if i could set a unique sound for one of them so i can tell if its just group chatter or someone specifically reaching out to me in a separate chat.

Comment: I see the question is related to teams product. Please reach out to the [Product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.